# How can i allow user to enter french characters in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I cannot make a search on a term with special character (éàùçêî...) like : Bérubé or Système

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the user is using a Latin character-set-based keyboard (such as US English or Français), they simply need to tap-hold the letter in question (for example, "e") on the soft keyboard in order to get access to the accented variants of "é" and so on. The user may not know this, so you may need to instruct them how to do this in your app (or website) help system.

If they're using a non-Latin keyboard, it's trickier. Then the user needs to add an additional Latin keyboard (such as US English or Français) in Settings.app via General->International->Keyboards, and then select the relevant keyboard by tapping the globe key that now appears on their soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Include the French keyboard in your simulator by going into the settings . Accordingly search in the `UITextField` then.